# Rails error do not understand newb expecting tASSOC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I apologize in advanced this is my first time posting a question.
This is my error that i do not understand or know how to correct this is the code that caused the error everything is working fine until this

c:/Sites/helpdesk/app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb:99: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting tASSOC
    redirect_to :action => 'show', :id = flash[:ticket_id]
                                        ^

```
#action
def ticket_action
  @act = Action.new(
        "ticket_id" => flash[:ticket_id],
        "description" => params[:description]['description'],
        "user_id" => params[:actUser]['user_id']
    )

  id @act.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Action was successfully added'
    redirect_to :action => 'show', :id = flash[:ticket_id]
    end
```

Comment: `:id = flash[:ticket_id]` should be `:id => flash[:ticket_id]`.

Comment: Zach Thank you so much. That was it I feel so dumb. Thank you so much now that my question has been answered what do i do with this question to mark it as answered?

Comment: You could ask @ZachKemp to post his comment as an anwser so you could accept (and upvote it maybe) it

Comment: Looks like somebody added this as a more detailed answer already, so go ahead and mark that one. Welcome to StackOverflow- for future reference, questions of this nature are typically closed or deleted as 'too localized'. Generally, syntax errors are easily solved using an editor that provides syntax checking, by looking at the line number indicated in the error, or by searching for keywords in the error message (e.g., 'tASSOC').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unexpected '=', expecting tASSOC redirect_to :action => 'show', :id = flash[:ticket_id]`

`tASSOC` is the `=>` symbol, so ruby is expecting `=>` instead of `=`
Just replace it in the line :

```
redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => flash[:ticket_id]
```

Which is equivalent to :

```
redirect_to { :action => 'show', :id => flash[:ticket_id] }
```

Ruby allows you to omit the `{}` when last parameter is a `Hash`

Plus

```
id @act.save
```

should be

```
if @act.save
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, when I change id @act.save to if I get an error. Replacing = with => fixes the error.

Comment: If you want to test if record was saved, you should use `if`. You'll need to add an `end` after your `redirect_to` line